# delphi embeddewb execute javascript for youtube

Tags: javascript, delphi, youtube, delphi-7

I am making my own delphi "youtube player"
as webbrowser i selected TEmbeddedWB...
But i dont want user intractions on the webpage, i have button and trackbars

button = mute / unmute video sound
trackbar1: set youtube volume
trackbar2: seek youtube play position

Can I execute javascripts to do this functions for me?

I googled one procedure:

```
 procedure ExecuteScript(doc: IHTMLDocument2; script: string; language: string) ;
 begin
 if doc <> nil then
 begin
  if doc.parentWindow <> nil then
   doc.parentWindow.ExecScript(script, Olevariant(language)) ;
   end; end;
```

and I want to call it (for example to mute sound):

```
executescript(ewbx.Document as IHTMLDocument2, ss, 'Javascript');
```

variable ss is widestring and it will contain javascripts to do things i mentioned above..

ss {scriptstring} :

```
ss:=
'var player;'+#13+#10+
'function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {'+#13+#10+
'    player = YT.Player('+quotedstr('ytplayer')+', {'+#13+#10+
'        events: {'+#13+#10+
'            '+quotedstr('onReady')+': onPlayerReady'+#13+#10+
'        }'+#13+#10+
'    });'+#13+#10+
'}'+#13+#10+
'function onPlayerReady(event) {'+#13+#10+
'    player.mute();'+#13+#10+
'    player.playVideo();'+#13+#10+'}';
```

but it not works, probably because YT.Player is not the correct component

Is this possible in Delpi 7 ?

Comment: update:  I googled around, and maybe this can work: **ss:='var myytplayer = document.getElementById('+quotedstr('ytplayer')+');';
ss:=ss+'myytplayer.pausevideo();';**      and then  **executescript(ewbx.Document as IHTMLDocument2, ss, 'Javascript');   **  But I am getting error **80020101**  that means something is wrong with my javascript..  When i am ignoring second line, i am not getting this error, so Javascript has problems with my second line of javascript:   **myytplayer.pausevideo();**